# How to uninstall a package from bitbucket

Tags: pip, django-piston

I have install django-piston with pip by running:

```
pip install -e hg+https://bitbucket.org/jespern/django-piston-oauth2#egg=django-piston-0.3dev
```

Now I want to uninstall it, but running...

```
pip uninstall -e hg+https://bitbucket.org/jespern/django-piston-oauth2#egg=django-piston-0.3dev
```

...just returns the following error:

```
Cannot uninstall requirement django-piston-0.3dev, not installed
```

So how do you uninstall django-piston then?

Answer (score 0):

Ok found my problem. The package installed is called django-piston and not django-piston-0.3dev. So to uninstall run:

```
pip uninstall hg+https://bitbucket.org/jespern/django-piston-oauth2#egg=django-piston
```